# How to compare 2 files and print all the lines from 2nd file to output file awk

Tags: linux, awk

I am trying to get the following output so basically. I have 2 input files and we need only the common :names from both the input files along with there the lines below them the .name/of/file lines

**Till now I have tried:**

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1]; next }NF<=1{ flag=0 }$1 in a { print; flag=1; delete a[$1]; next }flag{ printf "%s\n",$0 }' file1 file2
```

**Output:**

```
:name1
    ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 1 ]
    ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 1 ]
:name3
    ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 24 ]
    ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 24 ]
:name4
    ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 3 ]
    ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 3 ]
    ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 3 ]
    ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 3 ]
```

**Input file1:**

```
:name1
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 1 ]
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 1 ]

:name2
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 1 ]

:name3
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 24 ]
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 24 ]

 :name1
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 40]
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 40 ]

:name4
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 3 ]
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 3 ]
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 3 ]
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 3 ]

:name5
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 6 ]
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 6 ]

:name4
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 10 ]
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 10 ]
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 10 ]
./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 10 ]
```

**Input file2:**

```
:name1 ABC123 12345
:name3 EFG789 67898
:name4 HIJ547 01234
```

**Required Outputfile**:

```
:name1 ABC123 12345
    ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 1 ]
    ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 1 ]
:name3 EFG789 67898
    ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 24 ]
    ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 24 ]
:name4 HIJ547 01234
    ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 3 ]
    ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 3 ]
    ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 3 ]
    ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 3 ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `awk`. Here we are storing each record from file2 in associative array `a` with the key as `$1`.

```bash
awk '
FNR == NR {
   a[$1] = $0
   next
}
!NF { flag = 0 }
$1 in a {
   print a[$1]
   flag = 1
   delete a[$1]
   next
}
flag {
   print "   " $0
}' file2 file1

:name1 ABC123 12345
   ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 1 ]
   ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 1 ]
:name3 EFG789 67898
   ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 24 ]
   ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 24 ]
:name4 HIJ547 01234
   ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 3 ]
   ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 3 ]
   ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 3 ]
   ./name/of/file [logfile] [ error in file coming since Day : 3 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following `awk` code.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  if($0~/^:name[0-9]+/){
    key=$0
    if(key in arr){ flag="" }
    else          { flag=1  }
    next
  }
  if(flag){
    arr[key]=(arr[key]?arr[key] ORS:"") $0
  }
  next
}
($1 in arr){
  print $0 ORS arr[$1]
}
' file1  file2
```

Comment: @aastha, could you please do check my answer also if this has worked for you? Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution for awk. It first builds an index from file2, then processes the lines from file1: Replace lines from file1 by values from index, and some flag handling for printing the paragraphs.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}/^$/{f=0}f;$0 in a{print a[$0];delete a[$0];f=1}' f2 f1
```

1. Build an index from file2 with the result line (`NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}`)
2. Unset flag when reading an empty line from file1 (`/^$/{f=0}`)
3. Print line from file1 if flag `f` is set (`f`)
4. When reading an indexed line from file1:

   1. print the corresponding line from file2 (`$0 in a{print a[$0]}`)
   2. delete the indexed value, because you only want the first match (`delete a[$0]`)
   3. set flag in order to print the entire paragraph (`f=1`)

For indentation, I'd just `| sed 's/^[^:]/    /'` to keep the awk simple.